# Javascript log into website

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, web

I'm trying to make a private HTML document on my flash drive that when launched, will log me into a website. I've searched and searched and I have yet to find someone online with the same problem, thus I could not find any help. This would be for sites that log in using the POST method of course. I know it's possible to request a page, but is it possible to control the elements inside of it?

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make a userscript with scriptish or a make it as a bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend something like KeePass to do this. Any website worth it's salt won't allow you to do a cross-domain POST.